# Getting java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.lang.ObjectRange in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to trigger aws lambda from jenkins pipeline.
I'm passing 2 dates, and the job will iterate for all the in between dates and invoke lambda.

Below is my code.

```
pipeline {

  stages {
    stage('call lambda') {
        steps { 
            call_all(params.START_DATE, params.END_DATE) 
            }
    }
  }
}

def call_all(start_date, end_date) {
    date1 = new Date(start_date)
    date2 = new Date(end_date)
    dates = (date1..date2)
    for(date in dates) { 
      call_by_date("${date.format('yyyy-MM-dd')}") 
    }
}

def call_by_date(job_date) {
    sh "echo calling my_lambda for ${job_date}"
    withAWS(role: "${getAWSRole()}", roleAccount: "${getAWSAccount()}", duration: 1800) {
        sh 'aws lambda invoke \
                    --region "us-XXXX-1" \
                    --function-name "my_lambda" \
                    --invocation-type Event \
                    --payload "{\"date\":\"${job_date}\" }" \
                    /tmp/response.json'
    }
}

def getAWSAccount() {
        return "my_account"
}

def getAWSRole() {
        return "my_role"
}
```

Now error I'm getting is `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.lang.ObjectRange`

Below is the detailed error log

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.withscript.WithScriptScript.script
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript@7847f3f4
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@3bda31f9
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@20e8ad6e
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2552a0ff
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2552a0ff
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: ffb96466-c857-41d5-8be1-31811c926bd6
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.lang.ObjectRange
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:274)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:89)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:199)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SerializableScript.writeObject(SerializableScript.java:26)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:89)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:199)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:89)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:199)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:116)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$1(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:577)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:554)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:537)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:461)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Groovy Range ist not serializable. Try `dates = (date1..date2).toList()`.

Comment: it worked, but now getting `An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xab`

Comment: ` sh """aws lambda invoke \
                    --region 'us-XXXX-1' \
                    --function-name 'my_lambda' \
                    --invocation-type Event \
                    --payload '{"date":"${job_date}" }' \
                    /tmp/response.json"""`